# Deleting and inserting nodes in a linked list behave differently (?)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to learn `linked lists` from King (2008) "C Programming: A Modern Approach", 2nd ed and I'm puzzled by the behaviour of the deletion operation as compared to the insertion operation.

The author writes (p. 429):

> Note that `add_to_list` doesn't modify the list pointer. Instead, it
> returns a pointer to the newly created node....Getting `add_to_list`
> to update `first`, turns out to be tricky.

Now while deleting the first node doesn't modify the original list, deleting nodes in the interior or the end does modify the original list. But `delete_from_list` is also making a copy of the `first` pointer, so why can it modify `first` (while `add_to_list` cannot)?

What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *delete_from_list(struct node *, int);
struct node *add_to_list(struct node *, int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // setup a linked list
  
  // list's head
  struct node *first= NULL;

  // first node
  struct node *new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->value= 10;
  new_node->next= first;
  first= new_node;

  //second node
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->value= 20;
  new_node->next= first;
  first= new_node;

  //third node
  new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->value= 40;
  new_node->next= first;
  first= new_node;

  //fourth node
  new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->value= 30;
  new_node->next= first;
  first= new_node;

  int i;
  struct node *head= first;

  
  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  printf("    Original nodes: ");
  for(i=0; head!= NULL; head= head->next, i++)
    printf("\n%d-ith value: %d ", i, head->value);
  printf("\n------------------------\n");


  struct node *first_no20= delete_from_list(first, 20);
  struct node *head_no20= first_no20;
  
  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  printf("    Nodes without 20: ");
  for(i=0; head_no20!= NULL; head_no20= head_no20->next, i++)
    printf("\n%d-ith value: %d ", i,head_no20->value);
  printf("\n------------------------\n");

  
  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  head=first;
  printf("    Original nodes: ");
  for(i=0; head!= NULL; head= head->next, i++)
    printf("\n%d-ith value: %d ", i, head->value);
  printf("\n------------------------\n");


  struct node *first_no30= delete_from_list(first, 30);
  struct node *head_no30= first_no30;
 
  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  printf("    Nodes without 30: ");
  for(i=0; head_no30!= NULL; head_no30= head_no30->next, i++)
    printf("\n%d-ith value: %d ", i,head_no30->value);
  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  

  printf("\n------------------------\n");
  printf("    Original nodes: ");
  head=first;
  for(i=0; head!= NULL; head= head->next, i++)
    printf("\n%d-ith value: %d ", i, head->value);
  printf("\n------------------------\n");

  return 0;

}


struct node *delete_from_list(struct node *list, int n) {
  struct node *cur, *prev;

  for(cur=list, prev=NULL;
      cur != NULL && cur->value !=n;
      prev= cur, cur= cur->next)
    ;

  if(cur == NULL)
    return list;
  if(prev== NULL)
    list= list->next;
  else
    prev->next= cur->next;
  free(cur);

  return list;
}

struct node *add_to_list(struct node *list, int n) {
  struct node *new_node;

  new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(new_node == NULL) {
    printf("Error: malloc failed in add_to_list\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  new_node->value = n;
  new_node->next= list;

  return new_node;
}
```

Comment: This code has too many pointers, all of them think they are THE official pointer to the first node on the list. The first node WILL change when adding to the list and MAY change if the node being deleted is the first node of the list. Draw it out with pen and paper to see and understand what's happening. There should be **ONE** pointer variable that is the official pointer to the first node of the list. Use that variable only for all deletes/adds...

Comment: I've spent the whole day on this issue without much success. What kind of drawing do you have in mind? Are you saying that the problem is with the way the list is created?

Comment: Why are you creating the nodes in the main function, while your add_to_list function has this already implemented? In general, the design is that the functions always return the pointer to the list (i.e., the first node in it).

Comment: At `struct node *first_no20= delete_from_list(first, 20);` the value stored in `first` now points to a node that has been free'd... It is a loose cannon... A few lines later there is `head=first;`... BANG! the cannon has fired a shot... Decide if `first` or `head` will ALWAYS be used to add/delete and be consistent... eg "head = delete( head, ..." Don't save the return value into some "spontaneous new idea of a pointer variable"...

Comment: @sim that's a good question. Because I wanted to do things "by hand".

Comment: I guess, what Fe2O3 means is, what I would also propose you to draw some example cases. An example is a list, i.e., a set of nodes with links in between. Just draw the structure of the links before and after each step your program is doing to understand the changes you make.

Comment: The book cited above on p. 427 constructs the list (if I did not misunderstand it) exactly as I am doing inside main; in that page also shown is a picture similar to what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this quote

> Note that add_to_list doesn't modify the list pointer. Instead, it
> returns a pointer to the newly created node....Getting add_to_list to
> update first, turns out to be tricky.

denotes the following.

When a new node is added to the list then all pointers to nodes (as for example the passed pointer and values of the data member `next`) that already exist in the list are not changed.

On the other hand, when a node is deleted then  pointers to nodes (as for example the pointer that points to the deleted node or the value of the data member `next` of the preceding node) can be changed.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So node deletion is somehow permanent whereas node addition is not. But this puzzles me since both functions call `list` in the same way, i.e. coping the `list` pointer; I fail to see why this different behaviour though. (I'm new to C, and that may well be the reason )

Comment: @utobi The function that inserts nodes does not change pointers to nodes. It adds a new node. Opposite to this function the function that deletes nodes changes pointers to nodes. For example if in main you will define pointers to each node of the current list then after a call of the function that inserts nodes they will not be changed and will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Having *tried*, in the comments under the OP, to *teach* that the plethora of pointers in the OP code was the source of the problem, there is little else one can do but demonstrate the correct use of ONE pointer to the first node of the evolving LL (and one useful pointer that can traverse the LL.)

Here is the `main()` function written to perform the apparently desired task.

```
int main( void ) {
    struct node *first = NULL;
    struct node *p = NULL;

    // first node
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->value = 10;
    p->next = first; first = p;

    //second node
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->value = 20;
    p->next = first; first = p;

    //third node
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->value = 40;
    p->next = first; first = p;

    //fourth node
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->value = 30;
    p->next = first; first= p;


    puts( "Created nodes:" );
    for( p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        printf( "[%d] ", p->value );
    puts( "\n------------------------" );

    first = delete_from_list( first, 20 );
    puts( "Nodes without 20:" );
    for( p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        printf( "[%d] ", p->value );
    puts( "\n------------------------" );


    first = delete_from_list( first, 30 );
    puts( "Nodes without 30:");
    for( p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        printf( "[%d] ", p->value );
    puts( "\n------------------------" );


    first = delete_from_list( first, 10 );
    puts( "Nodes without 10:");
    for( p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        printf( "[%d] ", p->value );
    puts( "\n------------------------" );

    printf( "There are no \"original nodes\". There are only those nodes on the list." );

    return 0;
}
```

Omitted is the verification of the success of those multiple `malloc()` calls. An exercise for the reader.

Comment: thank you for your patience and for cleaning up my code! I see now what you meant in the comments. So deleting nodes does modify the original list. Sorry for the dumb comments,, I'm new to C.

Comment: There is no "original list"; there is only "the list as it is NOW". One might argue that the "original list" is the empty list at the top of the code before any nodes were added... A "linked list" is a dynamic "data structure"... Nodes are kicked off and added to suit the needs of the program. I do hope this helps. Cheers...